# Switch from terminal style output to clickable output in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I don't know the names for these things so I will attatche an image. Bassically I am used to being able to click through a dataframe inline on Rmarkdown. I just installed a freash version of R and Rstudio on my machine and the output looks like console output and it is not clickable. How do I change this?

[image]

This is what I would like

[image]

Note the ability to "thumb-through" the data by clicking "Previous" and "Next".

Comment: In RStudio open the file as if you would an .R script. You seem to be loading the file in the R console.

Comment: I don't think that is my problem.

Comment: What do you mean "click through a dataframe inline on Rmarkdown"? Are you referring to viewing the dataframe demonstrated here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205175388-Using-the-Data-Viewer ?

Comment: I think the question is why tables in Rmarkdown notebooks aren't being printed as paged tables, but are instead printed out the same way as in the console. I noticed this recently as well, I think after installing R 3.5, but this question is very unclear

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @camille explanation, I tracked down the issue. It's a known bug in R v3.5 and an issue has been opened on github:

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1331